# Does Automatic MIXED PRECISION (AMP) half the paramters of a model?

Tags: pytorch, automatic-mixed-precision

Before I knew about automatic mixed precision, I manually halved the model and data using half() for training with half precision. But the training result is not good at all.

Then I used the automatic mixed precision to train a network, which returns decent results. But when I save the checkpoint, the parameters in the checkpoints are still in fp32. I want to save a checkpoint with fp16. Therefore, I want to ask if and how I can save the checkpoints with fp16. And this also makes me wonder: when performing conv2d with autocast, are the parameters of conv2d also halved? Or is it only the data that is halved?

Comment: By the way, I want to save the checkpoints to fp16 because I want to use half precision for the inference.

Answer (score 1):

It does not apply "half" for all parameters. It analyzes each layer separately and some work with FP16 and others with FP32.

From the documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/amp_recipe.html).

> torch.cuda.amp provides convenience methods for mixed precision, where
> some operations use the torch.float32 (float) datatype and other
> operations use torch.float16 (half). Some ops, like linear layers and
> convolutions, are much faster in float16 or bfloat16. Other ops, like
> reductions, often require the dynamic range of float32. Mixed
> precision tries to match each op to its appropriate datatype, which
> can reduce your network’s runtime and memory footprint.

About the checkpoints, a copy of the weights is maintained in the FP32 precision to be by the optimizer, as said [here](https://pytorch.org/blog/scaling-vision-model-training-platforms-with-pytorch/#32-addressing-optimization-challenges-with-advanced-amp-and-kernel-fusion).